# Terminal do vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou com duvida no terminal do `vscode` com *Python*:

Quando entro na pasta do produto e digito *Python* aparece a versão 2, porem no rodapé do `vscode` está identificado como *Python 3*.

Quando digito python 3 aparece:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldades para usar o terminal, gostaria de um link com dicas. Sei que é uma questão simples, porém estou travado nisso aí.

Comment: Você esta usando Mac? Se sim, você precisa baixar o versão 3.x do python no site: https://www.python.org/

Comment: Que "pasta do produto" é essa?

Comment: Ja baixei tudo, nao estou conseguindo ter o domínio estou na aula 55 a 71 da COD3R na udemy ja refiz este modulo para saber o que estou pulando e nada.
Ja baixei a versão 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O terminal integrado do vscode não tem nenhuma relação com o próprio vscode, se você deseja executar códigos escritos em python3, você precisa digitar python3 arquivo.py .

Aquele python que aparece no vscode como propriamente dito, só influencia se vc for fazer um run ou um debug pelo próprio vscode, detecção de libs instaladas (linting), dentre outras coisas.

NOTA: python3 precisa ser junto, sem espaços.